# MS BotFramework in Node.js returns "default_error" for every message

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm trying to run the "hello world" example in Node.js in my localhost, using the Bot Framework Emulator. But for every message I sent from emulator the bot returns "default_error".

```
"botbuilder": "~3.5.3",
"restify": "~4.3.0"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of mine is the version of Node.js too old (v0.10.x in Ubuntu 14.04).
And issue had been fixed by upgrading Node.js to v7.4.0.

Please refer to the link:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1734